# what is difference between aws database service vs database engine

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

am looking to compare the aurora DB and RDS DB in aws. I see that aurora can also use RDS behind the scenes.

I have worked in sybase and sql server in the past. For these difference is clear as they are two different products with their own SQL and admin consoles. I couldn't draw similar picture for aws databases.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the deployment, escalation and managing tools that AWS (or GCP's Database) offers you. The engine (Aurora in your case) is the component that those services use to CRUD data from the Databases they manage.

[Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)
[Google Cloud databases](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=latam-MX-all-es-dr-SKWS-all-all-trial-p-dr-1009897-LUAC0015905&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_536282977841-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20SKWS%20-%20PHR%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Databases_General-KWID_43700065338782964-kwd-22539602&utm_term=KW_database-ST_Database&gclid=Cj0KCQjw18WKBhCUARIsAFiW7JxRMCerJzCMwXDNz9pC-KdgiK_75PDQlud2EFtAwl2fEGyIrVnCaeMaAltNEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 0):

Database service is something that is wrapped around your engine to help you with database management. Database engines are - like MySQL, MariaDB and Aurora where the transaction actually happens.

EDIT: Like AWS RDS is the database service which might use anyone of the six engines provided by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS is Relational database service. You can provision  MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, SQL Server, or PostgreSQL database. Main advantages is that aws will take care of provisioning infrastructure, operating system patching, database patching ,backups etc. so you can focus on what is important to the business.

Amazon Aurora comes under same family of Amazon RDS service. Amazon Aurora provides MySQL and Postgres compatible Editions.  The code, tools, and applications you use today with your existing MySQL and PostgreSQL databases can be used with Aurora. Aurora Postgres or MySQL is cheaper and faster compared to corresponding RDS Postgres or MySQL

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/is-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-or-amazon-aurora-postgresql-a-better-choice-for-me/